# What is the best way Loading XML data to mySql using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, xml

I am already working on a project to optimize interactions with dataBases using JAVA. 
First Step , I began with loading  XML data to mysql. 
I found many articles working on this issue , and they parse Data before inserting it  , like this article : 
https://dzone.com/articles/load-xml-into-mysql-using-java

But I tried to do things simpler : so 
I write this code that load data using LOAD local XML infile .. ( an sql Query )  and it works well .

```
package my.project;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class App {
  static final String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbOptimization";
  static final String password = "azerty";
  static final String user = "root";
  public Connection conn; 

  /*
   * Load jdbc Driver
   */
  static {
    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      System.out.println("Dirver loaded");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      System.err.println("Cannot load driver " + ex);
    }
  }

  /*
   * Connect to DB
   */
  public void connect() {
    try {
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, password);
      System.out.println("Database connected!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.err.println("Cannot connect the database!");
    }
  }

  /*
   * Create Table and Load Data
   */
  public void createTable() {
    try {
     conn.createStatement().execute("create Table badges(Id INTEGER,UserId VARCHAR(20),Name varchar(20),Date DATE ,Class INTEGER ,TagBased VARCHAR(20))");
      System.out.println("table created");
      conn.createStatement().execute("Load xml local infile '/home/lenovo/Bureau/Project/3dprinting/Badges.xml'into Table badges(Id,UserId,Name,Date,Class,TagBased)");
      System.out.println("data parsed");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("connot create Table" + e);
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    App app =new App();
    app.connect();
    app.createTable();
  }
}
```

So please , Is there any problem with my code .?!
What are the pros and cons of each method ?
which one has a better performence ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether or not you're going to use the XML as a whole document or not.

If you use XPath to search inside the document parsing and loading might make sense.

Comment: the objectif is to load data from an xml file to mysql table .
and both methods are only doing this . 
even , when they parse the xml file , the goal is to use this parsed data to insert it in the mys  lTable
Am I wrong ? or perhaps I didn't get what do you mean

Comment: If you never search inside the document to access it, there's no reason to parse in the database.  If you always use the entire document and access it using an id or meta data you could use a NoSQL alternative.

Comment: Thanks duffymo, the second step will be a NoSQL alternative. But for now , I have just to load the entire file into mysql and then make some sql queries